# Imported variable not defined in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with a Vue.js application (version 2.4).
I have created an event.js file that defines my eventBus as follow:

```
import Vue from "vue";

const EventBus = new Vue();

export default EventBus;
```

In other components I import that file and use EventBus to catch/emit various events. The problem is when I try to pass it as a property for another component:

```
                      <canvas-overlay
                          :eventBus="eventBus"
                          :fn="getBuildings">
                      </canvas-overlay>
  </template>
  <script>
  import CanvasOverlay from "components/src/core/Map/CanvasOverlaySingleEl.vue";
  import eventBus from "../../event";
  console.log(eventBus);

  export default {
      ...
  }
```

The output of the console.log is legit:

```
Vue$3 {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$3, …}$attrs: (...)$children: []$createElement: ƒ (a, b, c, d)$listeners: (...)$options: {components: {…}, directives: {…}, filters: {…}, _base: ƒ}$parent: undefined$refs: {}$root: Vue$3 {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$3, …}$scopedSlots: {}$slots: {}$vnode: undefined_c: ƒ (a, b, c, d)_data: {__ob__: Observer}_directInactive: false_events: {close-modal: Array(1), event: Array(1), map-moved: Array(1), address-search: Array(1), delete-credit-card: Array(1), …}_hasHookEvent: false_inactive: null_isBeingDestroyed: false_isDestroyed: false_isMounted: false_isVue: true_renderProxy: Proxy {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$3, …}_self: Vue$3 {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$3, …}_staticTrees: null_uid: 0_vnode: null_watcher: null_watchers: []$data: (...)$http: (...)$isServer: (...)$promise: (...)$props: (...)$resource: (...)$ssrContext: (...)$url: (...)get $attrs: ƒ reactiveGetter()set $attrs: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get $listeners: ƒ reactiveGetter()set $listeners: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)__proto__: Object
```

So I have the busEvent in the component. The problem is that in the child component (in this case canvas-overlay) the eventBus is undefined.

That's the definition of the prop:

```
      eventBus: {
          type: Object,
          required: true,
      },
```

What am I missing?

Comment: in the component where you do `import eventBus from "../../event";`
is eventBus in the data() object of that component?

Comment: You were right, thanks!